# Wordpress orderby Custom Field Value

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this code to sort the menu options available to an interactive Bing Map.  The code provided is what creates the listing elements for the menu in each category.  The problem I am having is, it is not ordering them by the Marker Number(mrk_num) which is a custom field that is declared in the back end of Wordpress.  I don't know if this is enough description to help define my problem so if you need more information I will try to provide it.

With the code provided the results show up but are not in the order that they should be.

```
function navItems($navSet){
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'territory_map',
                   'posts_per_page' => -1,
                   'meta_value' => $navSet,
                   'orderby'=>'mrk_num',
                   'order'=>'ASC'
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    $mrkNum = get_custom_field('mrk_num');

    echo '<li><a onclick="activateInfoBox('.get_the_id().', $(this))" href="#">' . $mrkNum . ' ' .get_the_title() . '</a></li>';

    endwhile;
}
```

$navSet is the name of the category that I pass to it when I call it from the HTML.  For example I will pass it 'Indoor Attractions'

The results appear but not in Ascending order based on the field mrk_num like it should be.  I am fairly new to this so I will try to supply anymore information that you might need.

Comment: this might help you? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4707/sort-by-custom-field-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, this should work.

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'territory_map',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'mrk_num',
    'orderby'=>'meta_value_num',
    'order'=>'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'your_key',
            'value' => $navSet,
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);
```

If it is not working, I already experienced what you are trying to achieve and the best way to go is to debug mysql queries (you can for example use this [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-queries/)) and add a filter on [posts_orderby](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby).

Comment: When I use the code you have provided, no results are returned.

Comment: Actually, I tried my code on a local installation of Wordpress and it's working. I don't see where you are stuck.

Comment: I think the issue is(and I am not 100% certain on this) that in your code you are sorting by meta_value and that is $navSet which really the category and I want to orderby mrk_num which is a value that the user sets in the back end.

Comment: OK I edited, I believed you want to filter your results with the value of your meta.

Comment: I believe this is closer to what I want but still not the results I expected.  I know I said it is the category but I should specify that $navSet is another meta_value that is set by the user in a dropdown in the back end.  So it is not using 'cat'.

Comment: A couple of things,(I think we are almost there! Appreciate the help) First off, minor, but typo you have 'meta_query' = array and should be 'meta_query' => array.

Comment: But the results I get are closer but it is ordering it like (1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,2,20,3,4) so need to change 'orderby' => 'meta_value' needs to be 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'.  These changes got me the results I needed. Once answer is edited again I will accept answer. Thank you so much!